# how to extract fields of info from github api using jq

Tags: shell, curl, json, jq, api

I am trying to extract some info about github repositories using its API, apparently `jq` is the way to go.
I can use this command to view all the available info:

```bsh
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm' | jq
```

Output:

```bsh
{
  "id": 19935788,
  "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxOTkzNTc4OA==",
  "name": "tpm",
  "full_name": "tmux-plugins/tpm",
  "private": false,
  "owner": {
    "login": "tmux-plugins",
    "id": 8289877,
    "node_id": "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjgyODk4Nzc=",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/8289877?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/tmux-plugins",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/received_events",
    "type": "Organization",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "html_url": "https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm",
  "description": "Tmux Plugin Manager",
  "fork": false,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm",
  "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/forks",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/keys{/key_id}",
  "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/collaborators{/collaborator}",
  "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/teams",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/hooks",
  "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/issues/events{/number}",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/events",
  "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/assignees{/user}",
  "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/branches{/branch}",
  "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/tags",
  "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/git/blobs{/sha}",
  "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/git/tags{/sha}",
  "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/git/refs{/sha}",
  "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/git/trees{/sha}",
  "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/statuses/{sha}",
  "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/languages",
  "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/stargazers",
  "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/contributors",
  "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/subscribers",
  "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/subscription",
  "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/commits{/sha}",
  "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/git/commits{/sha}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/comments{/number}",
  "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/issues/comments{/number}",
  "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/contents/{+path}",
  "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/compare/{base}...{head}",
  "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/merges",
  "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/{archive_format}{/ref}",
  "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/downloads",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/issues{/number}",
  "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/pulls{/number}",
  "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/milestones{/number}",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/labels{/name}",
  "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/releases{/id}",
  "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm/deployments",
  "created_at": "2014-05-19T09:18:38Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-03T04:30:43Z",
  "pushed_at": "2021-02-23T11:07:55Z",
  "git_url": "git://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm.git",
  "ssh_url": "git@github.com:tmux-plugins/tpm.git",
  "clone_url": "https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm.git",
  "svn_url": "https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm",
  "homepage": null,
  "size": 204,
  "stargazers_count": 6861,
  "watchers_count": 6861,
  "language": "Shell",
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_downloads": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_pages": false,
  "forks_count": 251,
  "mirror_url": null,
  "archived": false,
  "disabled": false,
  "open_issues_count": 79,
  "license": {
    "key": "mit",
    "name": "MIT License",
    "spdx_id": "MIT",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz"
  },
  "forks": 251,
  "open_issues": 79,
  "watchers": 6861,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "temp_clone_token": null,
  "organization": {
    "login": "tmux-plugins",
    "id": 8289877,
    "node_id": "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjgyODk4Nzc=",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/8289877?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/tmux-plugins",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmux-plugins/received_events",
    "type": "Organization",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "network_count": 251,
  "subscribers_count": 83
}
```

1. How would I extract just the "description"?
2. How do I extract the "language" & "description"?

I ask question 2 as I have seen examples online (when trying to find an answer for myself), that show multiple fields being extracted in one, this would be helpful to me and others finding this question.
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In all cases below, `file.json` is the name of a file containing your JSON document.  You could obviously use `jq` as you've done in the question instead,  and have it read from a pipe connected to the output of `curl`.

Pulling the requested fields out, one by one:

```
$ jq -r '.description' file.json
Tmux Plugin Manager
$ jq -r '.language' file.json
Shell
```

The `-r` option is used above (and below) to get the "raw data" rather than JSON encoded data.

Getting both at once (you'd have issues telling them apart if any of them contain embedded newline characters):

```
$ jq -r '.language, .description' file.json
Shell
Tmux Plugin Manager
```

Getting them as a CSV record (will be properly quoted so that embedded commas and newlines will be parsable by a CSV parser, and embedded double quotes will be CSV encoded too):

```
$ jq -r '[.language, .description] | @csv' file.json
"Shell","Tmux Plugin Manager"
```

Tab-delimited (embedded newlines and tabs will show up as `\n` and `\t` respectively):

```
$ jq -r '[.language, .description] | @tsv' file.json
Shell   Tmux Plugin Manager
```

Letting `jq` produce shell code containing two variable assignments. The values will be properly quoted for the shell.

```
$ jq -r '@sh "lang=\(.language)", @sh "desc=\(.description)"' file.json
lang='Shell'
desc='Tmux Plugin Manager'
```

Getting the shell to actually evaluate these statements:

```
$ eval "$( jq -r '@sh "lang=\(.language)", @sh "desc=\(.description)"' file.json )"
$ printf 'lang is "%s" and desc is "%s"\n' "$lang" "$desc"
lang is "Shell" and desc is "Tmux Plugin Manager"
```

Comment: Now THATS an answer! Not only showing what I asked, but go a step further too: How to format (`\n`/`\t`), as `csv` and the variable assignment is VERY clever, especially for scripting. Thank you so much, it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How would I extract just the "description"?

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm' | jq -r '.description'
Tmux Plugin Manager
```

> 2. How do I extract the "language" & "description"?

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/tmux-plugins/tpm'
   | jq -r '.language + ": " + .description'
Shell: Tmux Plugin Manager
```

The second terminal command should preferably be on just *one* row.
If you copy-paste the two lines in one go, try using
<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> for pasting into the terminal.

**Note:** just remove the `-r` flag if you prefer to get the answers as strings.